# Extracting particular value using regex in splunk

Tags: splunk

In the below event "status" key has the value either  "1" or "0".
I am looking out to extract those "status" having the value "0" and put them in a field

please help me out in getting a regular expression for this.

```
- 2017-02-14 18:47:28.572 INFO  SomePlaceHolder-5 [.abc.def.nothingishere]  - string response: <200 OK,{"clips":[{"myid":"123456","historyid":"777-888-999","provider":"somecompany","status":1,"userType":1}]},{X-Backside-Transport=[OK OK], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Content-Type=[application/json], X-Powered-By=[ARR/3.0,ASP.NET], Date=[Tue, 14 Feb 2017 18:47:28 GMT], X-Client-IP=[10.0.0.0.], X-Global-Transaction-ID=[9876543]}>
```

Comment: You can create the regex by using the "patterns" tab, the tab is placed above the search result.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it should be rex, can you edit the title back?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming Splunk hasn't already extracted these automatically (it looks close to JSON, perhaps), this will do it:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| rex field=_raw "status\":(?<status>\d+)"
| search status=0
```